# SQL auto expand relationships

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I'm using MS Access 2003/2007.

This is a simplified scenario but hopefully helps clarify. I have a table called `TableAB` that consists of 2 columns as follows:

[image: TableAB]

`FieldA` is used to populate a UserForm multiselect Listbox which then allows users to select one or more items to search.  The selected items are then used to search a separate primary table that contains several thousand records.

`FieldB` describes 4 relationship sets (9, 10, 19 and 28) between certain items in `FieldA`, and allows us to auto-expand the search selection, if a separate “Auto” user switch is enabled.

For example, if the selected search items are 2, 10 and 11 then the auto expanded search would be 2,10,11,25,26,34,66. Here, 25, 26, 34 and 66 are auto included.

I can auto expand using the above example with the following:

```
SELECT FieldA    
FROM TableAB    
WHERE FieldA In (2,10,11) Or FieldB In (2,10,11);
```

**My problem:**

Where a user selects all items of a particular relationship but does not select the primary item describing that relationship (the item in `FieldB`), then, I would like that item to be auto included (no user switch is required since the missing item should always be included).

For example, if the user selects 23 and 24 then I would like 9 to be included – but only providing the user entered both 23 and 24

I can return the primary relationship item using the following as an example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FieldB   
FROM tblABC         
WHERE  (FieldA In (1,2,9,30,68) And FieldB <> Null) Or FieldB In(1,2,9,30,68);
```

But I’m finding it difficult, due to my limited SQL knowledge, to think of a way to achieve my goal simply/elegantly without resorting to interfacing too much with Visual Basic, something I could do but would prefer not to. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following query does what you want:

```
SELECT FieldA    
FROM TableAB    
WHERE FieldA In (9) Or FieldB In (9)
UNION
SELECT FieldB
FROM TableAB as ab
GROUP BY FieldB
HAVING SUM(IIF(FieldA in (9), 1, 0)) = COUNT(*) AND
       COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableAB WHERE FieldA in (9) AND ab.FieldB = TableAB.FieldB)
```

The second `select` adds the higher level relationship.  The `having` clause checks that all the values for a given `FieldB` match back to your list and only to your list.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! With the missing Right bracket placed at the end of HAVING SUM(IIF(FieldA in (9), 1, 0)) the result is very close to what I want but it's still problematic. The "In (9)" will be substituted for the user selection. If I substitute (9) for (23,24) then the return is 9,23,24 - exactly what I want. But, if I enter (23,24,68,69) then the return is 23,24,68,69 - it should include 9 and 28.

Comment: @Jim . . . Very interesting situation.  If you have more than one complete group, then the original query wouldn't work.  The solution is a correlated subquery.  I think think have the correlation correct for your data.

Comment: @Gordon...many,many thanks for your help here. 
In substituting (9) for (1,2,10,23,68,69) I get 1,2,10,23,25,26,28,34,66,68,69…everything I want but the 10 is auto expanded to include 25,26,34,66 which I don’t want. Auto expansion where the user selects an entry also present in field B needs to be kept restricted to a switch the user can enable or disable. I currently have this facility working elsewhere before the final strSQL is constructed.

Comment: With a very small modification – substituting “WHERE FieldA In (1,2,10,23,68,69) Or FieldB In (1,2,10,23,68,69)” with “WHERE FieldA In (1,2,10,23,68,69)” we prevent the 10 from auto expanding. The result of this, alongside the missing primary relationship item returns after the UNION (i.e. the extra 28 via 68 and 69), now gets us everything including all missing primary items, so far tested. Again, many thanks. Now, I’m keen to deconstruct and take a closer look at how you managed this wizardry.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Gordon's working solution, I'm thinking that I can reduce this further by omitting everything after the first COUNT(*) to give the following, in total:-

```
SELECT FieldA    
FROM TableAB    
WHERE FieldA In (1,10,23,24,68) Or FieldB In (1,10,23,24,68)
```

Output --> 1,10,23,24,25,26,34,66,68 (---> where the 10 is auto expanded to include 25,26,34,66)

The `Or FieldB In (1,10,23,24,68)` is user-switch dependant and allows the user to auto expand, to the full collection, using the matching Field B item as the relationship link. The UserForm code will insert this optional segment as required.

**What we're missing from this (i.e. the main question) is the missing relationship key value** - "9" in this example. This value should be included because all relationship items are included i.e. 23 and 24.

As in @Gordon's solution (slightly reduced), we'll add the following:-

```
UNION
SELECT FieldB
FROM TableAB
GROUP BY FieldB
HAVING SUM(IIF(FieldA In (1,10,23,24,68), 1, 0)) = COUNT(*);
```

Output --> 9, and the total combined output from both halves gives me exactly what I want.

Now, if I'm decoding this correctly, since we're GROUPing BY FieldB then `SUM(IIF(FieldA In (1,10,23,24,68), 1, 0))` counts the total number of matching FieldB hits for each item. Then, `= COUNT(*)` returns, for each respective FieldB item, what the total should be for a full match (i.e. all relationship items are present for that collection). `HAVING` restricts the returned dataset to only those meeting the full match criteria.

-->is this, roughly, what's going on here and is it safe to reduce Gordon's solution in this way?